# What do the symbols mean after running :ls in Vim?

Tags: vim

After running the list buffers command (`:ls`) in Vim, what do the symbols displayed before some buffers mean? I know the percent sign (`%`) indicates the currently visible buffer. However, I also see the hash sign (`#`), and I can't figure out what that means. Googling this has proved fruitless.

Comment: To whomever downvoted: could you please explain why? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote but as a rule of thumb: if you have any question regarding a vim command, asking vim for help is often not the worst idea: as pb2q answers, a simple `:he :ls` gives you anything you need...

Comment: @eckes Thanks for the info. I'm very new to Vim and didn't realize I could do that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

See [`:help :ls`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:ls).

The hash sign marks the *alternate buffer*. This is useful for switching between two buffers: it's the buffer that you'll switch to when using e.g. `:b#`. This is the only thing resembling *most recently used* that you'll get with vim buffers, without plugins.

You also know from `:ls` which buffers have unsaved modifications: `+`.

Comment: `:help :ls` is better, `:help ls` may pick some tag defined in some of the plugins.

Comment: @tnorthcutt If you're happy with the answer you should accept it.